# How can I do OR- ing with JQuery or CSS in a single selector?

Tags: jquery, css

I need to write a single CSS selector like (Not [multiple selectors](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/))

```
a[href^='javascript:' OR href='']
```

I see AND-ing options but not an OR-ing.
Is it possible to achieve this in JQuery or CSS3?

An example where I can use this is

```
$(document.body).on('mouseover', "a[href^='javascript:' OR href='']", function(){});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

```
$('a[href^="javascript:"], a[href=""]')
```

Comment: Given the context I provided in this question, multiple selector option is good. But I am trying to do OR-ing with a single selector. You cannot readily use multiple selectors say for eg: in `$(document.body).on('mouseover',"a[href^='javascript:' OR href='']",function() {});` I will edit my question to reflect this

Comment: Great.That works Arun. Could you please point me to the JQuery documentation which allows splitting of selectors with comma?

Comment: Wasn't that apparent to me with in the on() API                     .on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler(eventObject) )

Comment: @santon it says `selector`, so any valid selectors can be passed as a selector there

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49698/discussion-between-santon-and-arun-p-johny)